# I need to get an object array through the data Table, using cucumber in cypress

Tags: typescript, datatables, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I need to get through the data Table an object array, using cucumber in cypress
In the cucumber file:

```
Given must present the values ​​in the requisition body.
| userid | segmentation           | date|

| 111    | [{"DateType": "day"} ] | {"StartDate": "1992-12-26", "EndDate": "2061-12-26"} |
```

in the ts file:

```
Given('must present the values ​​in the request body', (dataTable) => {
  const columns = Object.keys(dataTable.hashes()[0]).length;
  const rows = dataTable.hashes().length;
  body = dataTable.hashes();

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      if(Object.values(body[i][j]).includes("{", 0)){
        console.log(Object.keys(body[i])[j]);
        console.log( (body[i])[j])
        body[i][j] = JSON.parse(Object.values(body[i])[j])
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(body)

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      expect(JSON.stringify(response.body)).to.have.string(JSON.stringify(Object.values(body[i])[j]));
    }
  }
})
```

I'm using typescrip and when reading the table I can't convert this segmentation into an object array or date into an object, can someone tell me if this is possible and how to do it?